# Hive: error when trying to map key and value

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a query like this where I am trying to convert `array<struct<key:string,value:array<string>>`  to `map<string,array<string>>`. 
The query is

```
SELECT name, address, location, map(collect_set(k1),collect_set(concat_ws("",v1))) AS key_one
FROM table_a 
lateral view inline(key_one) t1 as k1,v1
GROUP BY name, address, location;
```

I get the error as `FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10016]: Line 1:62 Argument type mismatch 'v1': Primitive Type is expected but array<string>" is found`

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you can not have complex data types (i.e. array, struct, map) as a key to map. 
And that make sense right. key has to be only one value so it has to be primitive (i.e String, Int, BigInt)

However, your code tries to put key as array and so the error.  What you need to do is first explode the array and then try to get the key and value to form a map.

This might work.

**create table**

```
create table temp.test_struct (test array<struct<key:string,value:array<string>>>)
```

**Insert values**

```
insert into temp.test_struct 
select array(
            NAMED_STRUCT("key", "k1", "value", array("a","b","c")), 
            NAMED_STRUCT("key", "k2", "value", array("x","y","z"))
            ) from (select 'a') x
```

**Convert Array of Struct to map**

```
select test, map(t1.key, t1.value) map_col
from 
    temp.test_struct
lateral view inline(test) t1
```

[image]